# I've accidentally added a number label in front of a file in Android Studio and I'm not sure how to get rid of it

Tags: android-studio

I was trying to refactor a filename in Android Studio when I accidentally mistyped the keyboard shortcut.

Since I have a 75% keyboard, I don't have F rows. So I tried to hit `Shift+FN+6`, which would result in inputting `Shift+F6`, which is the keyboard shortcut for refactoring. But because of my typo, I hit some other keyboard command. Probably did `<some keys> + 6` by accident.

Now there's a little `6` label listed in front of the filename:

[image]

Does anyone know what shortcut I accidentally hit, so I can undo it? I found an SO user who [did the same thing as me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54692208/a-number-icon-appeared-before-a-filename-in-android-studio) but he got no replies. I tried hitting a bunch of random shortcuts and looking in the options menu but I can't find the option that I must've hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf

Android Studio is based on Idea and inherits its features.

I'm guessing this could be the numbered bookmarks feature. Try Shift-F11 to list all bookmarks or Ctrl-F11 to toggle it.